# Replace all statuses inside an array of objects with (find & filter) don't works

Tags: javascript

I've a problem. I'm trying to replace any occurrence of my `subscribed` status inside my array of object with my `pending` status.

First I've tried it with `.find()` but this changed only the first element. So I did some research on SO and found out that `.find(`) stops after the first occurrence. The solution to the question was `.filter()` but somehow it's still not working:

```js
let subscribedChannels = [];

subscribedChannels.push( {
 name: "ABC",
 status: "subscribed"
} );

subscribedChannels.push( {
 name: "DEF",
 status: "subscribed"
} );

subscribedChannels.push( {
 name: "GHI",
 status: "subscribed"
} );

console.log(subscribedChannels);

subscribedChannels.find( channel => channel.status === "subscribed" ).status = "pending"; //Not working because stopping after first element

console.log(subscribedChannels);

subscribedChannels.filter( channel => channel.status === "subscribed" ).status = "pending"; //Also not working but don't know why

console.log(subscribedChannels);
```

Comment: Use `map` here. `arr.map(a => { conditionHere, changeData in a; return a;})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to acces `each` so use `forEach`

I do not think `filter` and `map` sounds semantically correct even though they would work - the first is to return a subset and the other to return a new array

```js
const subscribedChannels = [
  { name: "ABC", status: "subscribed"},
  { name: "DEF", status: "done"},
  { name: "GHI", status: "subscribed"}
];
console.log(JSON.stringify(subscribedChannels));


subscribedChannels.forEach(channel => {
  if (channel.status === "subscribed") channel.status = "pending"
});

// without the brackets
// subscribedChannels.forEach(c => c.status = c.status === "subscribed" ? "pending" : c.status);

console.log(JSON.stringify(subscribedChannels));
```

***NOTE*** if you need to CHAIN the array and for example filter after change, you should use map

```js
const subscribedChannels = [
  { name: "ABC", status: "subscribed"},
  { name: "DEF", status: "done"},
  { name: "GHI", status: "subscribed"}
];


console.log(JSON.stringify(subscribedChannels));

const done = subscribedChannels
  .map(c => { c.status = c.status === "subscribed" ? "pending" : c.status; return c; }) // not the return c
  .filter(c => c.status === "done")

console.log(JSON.stringify(subscribedChannels));
console.log(JSON.stringify(done));
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Is there a short function style too?

Comment: How much shorter do you want it?

Comment: Just kidding. It's perfect. Thank you! I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: `subscribedChannels.forEach(c => c.status = c.status === "subscribed" ? "pending" : c.status);`

Answer (score 2):

You can run something like:

```js
const subscribedChannels = [
  { name: "ABC", status: "subscribed"},
  { name: "DEF", status: "done"},
  { name: "GHI", status: "subscribed"}
];

console.log(subscribedChannels.map(c => {
      c.status = c.status == "subscribed" ?
        "pending" :
        c.status; return c;
    }).filter(c => c.status=="done")
)
```

Comment: Why map? Why not just [forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987250/295783)? It makes more sense since we do not need a new array. Anyway your answer is otherwise identical to mine

Comment: I guess it's more functional, also since `forEach` returns undefined, it's not chainable.

Comment: Well, by the definition of functional programming you want to avoid side-effects and mutable data, and I assume since it's using JS that it's not performance critical so creating new arrays should be cheap.

Comment: Hmm, I see the point with the chainability. But I cannot believe creating a new array is without costs - also I like the semantics of it

Comment: Of course there are costs involved, like with any line of code someone could write. I'd say that in this particular case (with the context that we have on the problem) it mostly boils down to personal preference.

Comment: I made you a snippet to test your theory. Your map is NOT filterable

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use map instead:

```
const pendingChannels = subscribedChannels.map(channel => {
  if(channel.status === "subscribed") {
    channel.status = "pending"
  }

  return channel
})
```

Comment: I don't want to create a new array. I just want to update the old one.

Comment: well, then just use subscribedChannels = subscribedChannels.map... instead.

Comment: Which is why forEach was made